# Comparing ddmmyy dates in bash

Tags: bash, date, scripting

I would like some help for a bash script to read all the files in a ftp directory and delete the ones after the date range stated on its name.

Each file would have a name such as 'title %m%d%Y %m%d%Y' (e.g.: Events 02172015 02192015.png). Is it possible to read all files in the directory comparing the names with the server date and delete the ones which date range is older than the current date?

Comment: `%m%d%Y` makes this needlessly complex (and also is confusing to human readers from parts of the world where `%d%m%Y` is convention). Is there a good reason you can't use `%Y%m%d` (which removes this ambiguity, and in which case a simple lexical comparison of the dates will tell you which is newer)?

Comment: If you can control things to that point, why not organize the files in folders `YYYY/MM/DD`... so that deleting them as time goes by is a trivial task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First -- change your filename format. Using `%Y%m%d` will greatly decrease the amount of pain and suffering involved (and, as a side effect, will make tools that sort by filename put your files in order by date automatically).

Answering your question as originally asked, however...

```
today=$(date +%Y%m%d)

# filter for filenames with at least two spaces and a period
for f in *" "*" "*.*; do
  without_extension=${f%.*}
  end_date=${without_extension##* }

  ## now, if you were using YYYYMMDD, you could just do this:
  # [[ $end_date < $today ]] && rm -f -- "$f"

  ## ...however, since you aren't, you need all this mess:
  mon=${end_date:0:2}
  day=${end_date:2:2}
  year=${end_date:4:4}
  end_date_sane=${year}${mon}${day}
  [[ $end_date_sane < $today ]] && rm -f -- "$f"

done
```

Comment: Thanks Charles, That's exactly what I needed. However, once my folder is in a FTP location, looks like I cannot use a shell script with a FTP connection :( http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55719/how-to-loop-through-each-file-in-ftp-directory-using-a-bash-script

Comment: "Cannot" is a little bit strong of a word. There are FUSE backends for FTP; using one of these would make your FTP resource look like a regular filesystem. See for instance http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/

Comment: It's also possible to run an FTP client as a coprocess from a shell script... that said, while possible, it's certainly not particularly easy, and not a great beginner's project.

Comment: Hey Charles, Just tried Curlftpfs and it worked great! Thanks for the suggestion!